# Los tipos estáticos no se pueden usar como argumentos de tipo [API] Error al configurar proveedor de base de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mariadb, .net-core, entity-framework-core

[Nivel de manejo de programación 1 al 10, estoy en el 4]

Buenos días, estoy tratando de realizar una api con tecnología Microsoft Net Core v5, y tengo problemas al tratar de configurar el servicios del proveedor de base de datos, que en este caso usare MariaDB.
El paquee que estoy utilizando para el proveedor de base es:
"Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql"

me da el siguiente error:

```
'AppContext': los tipos estáticos no se pueden usar como argumentos de tipo [API]"
```

A que se debe este error? ó que estoy haciendo mal?

Empezare dejando:
API.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="5.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ServerDB": "Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

ParqueNacionales.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class ParqueNacional
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public DateTime Creado { get; set; }
        public DateTime Establecido { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            // ConnectionString

            //
            services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(
                options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ServerDB"))
            );
            //
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

AppContext.cs

```
using API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Data
{
    public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppContext (DbContextOptions<AppContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ParqueNacional> ParquesNacionales { get; set; }
    }
}
```

dotnet --info

```
Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0
  Commit:  cf258a14b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es con el nombre de la clase `AppContext` que has utilizado para el contexto de base de datos.

`AppContext` es también una clase estática definida en el namespace `System` para mantener el contexto de la aplicación.

En el `Startup` estás haciendo referencia a esa otra clase (al incluir una sentencia `using System`) en lugar de a la tuya.

Si eliminas el `using System;` y lo reemplazas por un `using API.Data` para que coja tu clase definida en ese namespace te funcionará sin problemas.

Aunque yo te recomendaría cambiar el nombre a tu clase para evitar confusiones y conflictos de nombres.